# Getting sum of associated array calculation

Tags: php

I am working on this demo code. How can I get the sum of associated array **while they multiplied** by **other element** in the array?

I need to multiple each `['Age']` to it's associated `['Rank']` and get the sum at end. so the result should be

```
(40 * 2) + (36 * 4) + (26 * 2) = 204
```

Here is the code:

```
 <?php

$arr = array(
     ["Name" => "Ali", "Age"=>40, "Rank"=>2],
     ["Name" => "John", "Age"=>36, "Rank"=>4],
     ["Name" => "Fred", "Age"=>26, "Rank"=>2],
);

$sum = array_sum(array_column($arr, 'Age'));

echo $sum;
```

Comment: you need to use default algorithms ? or you can write your own code manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using "custom" code you can do it like so:

```
$arr = array(
     ["Name" => "Ali", "Age"=>40, "Rank"=>2],
     ["Name" => "John", "Age"=>36, "Rank"=>4],
     ["Name" => "Fred", "Age"=>26, "Rank"=>2],
);

$sum = 0;
foreach ($arr as &$el)
    $sum += $el['Age'] * $el['Rank'];

echo $sum;
```

Or you probably also can do something like this:

```
$sum = array_reduce($arr, function($carry, $item) {
    return $carry + $item['Age'] * $item['Rank'];
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to sum a custom function (the age value multiplied by the rank value):

```php
$sum = array_reduce($arr, function($carry, $item) {
    $carry += ($item['Age'] * $item['Rank']);
    return $carry;
});
```